# Ionic2 JWT authentication failed with Django rest framework backend

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building an Ionic 2 app and I am trying to use JWT to authenticate my users as shown here: https://auth0.com/blog/2016/02/18/ionic-2-authentication-how-to-secure-your-mobile-app-with-jwt/.

On clicking 'login' server sends back the token which I can see in my developer console network, however I get following error on console: (Error in build/pages/profile/profile.html:8:29 & ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Error: JWT must have 3 parts.)Additionally I have to clear cookies everytime!

**My profile.ts:**

```
import {Page, Storage, LocalStorage} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import {JwtHelper} from 'angular2-jwt';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth/auth.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { StartPage } from '../start/start.component';


@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/profile/profile.html',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class ProfilePage {
  LOGIN_URL: string = " http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/";
  SIGNUP_URL: string = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration/";

  auth: AuthService;
  // When the page loads, we want the Login segment to be selected
  authType: string = "login";
  // We need to set the content type for the server
  contentHeader: Headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
  error: string;
  jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
  local: Storage = new Storage(LocalStorage);
  user: string;  

  constructor(private http: Http, public nav:NavController) {
    this.auth = AuthService;
    this.local.get('profile').then(profile => {
      this.user = JSON.parse(profile);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  login(credentials) {
    this.http.post(this.LOGIN_URL, JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: this.contentHeader })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => this.authSuccess(data.id_token),
        err => this.error = err
      );
  }

  signup(credentials) {
    this.http.post(this.SIGNUP_URL, JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: this.contentHeader })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => this.authSuccess(data.id_token),
        err => this.error = err
      );
  }

  logout() {
    this.local.remove('id_token');
    this.user = null;
  }

  authSuccess(token) {
    this.error = null;
    this.local.set('id_token', token);
    this.user = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);

  }
}
```

**My service:**

```
import {tokenNotExpired} from 'angular2-jwt';

export class AuthService {
  constructor() {}

  public static authenticated() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }
}
```

**My profile.html:**

```
<!-- app/profile/profile.html -->
  <ion-navbar *navbar>
    <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
    <ion-title>Profile</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

  <ion-content class="login" *ngIf="!auth.authenticated()">

      <div padding>
        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="authType">
          <ion-segment-button value="login">
            Login
          </ion-segment-button>
          <ion-segment-button value="signup">
            Signup
          </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
      </div>

      <div [ngSwitch]="authType">
        <form *ngSwitchWhen="'login'" #loginCreds="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginCreds.value)">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" ngControl="email"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" ngControl="password"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

          <div padding>
            <button block type="submit">Login</button>        
          </div>

        </form>

        <form *ngSwitchWhen="'signup'" #signupCreds="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="signup(signupCreds.value)">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" ngControl="username"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" ngControl="password"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

          <div padding>
            <button block type="submit">Signup</button>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>

      <div padding>
        <p *ngIf="error" class="error">{{ error._body }}</p>  
      </div>

  </ion-content>

  <ion-content>
    <div *ngIf="auth.authenticated()">
      <div padding>
        <h1>Welcome, {{ user }}</h1>
        <button block (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

[image]

On successful login I would like to navigate to a specific page. What's going wrong and how can I fix this?

Also, the token I get back from my backend (**I am using Django-rest-auth in my backend for authentication**):

[image]

Comment: I think there may be a problem with your backend. [JWT tokens must have three parts delimited by dots, e.g. xxxx.yyyy.zzzz](https://jwt.io/introduction/#what-is-the-json-web-token-structure-), it looks like your Ionic2 app is working correctly, but your web service is not returning a valid token, so it is throwing an error.

Comment: Yes. Follow the link in my previous comment and read the docs.